# Spring boot mvn plugin for ARM64

Tags: spring-boot, docker, arm, maven-plugin

I'm built a small spring boot MQTT application I am going to run on a raspberry pi. I've pulled the generated image, however it is failing on the pi since docker images are generally built fr x64.

Is there a way with the spring boot plugin to specify the architecture where the `docker buildx` will be utilized? I've had a brief look through the spring boot mvn plugin but not seeing anything like that.